# How do you create a simple password protected React app? A single password that would be used by everyone at, say, a conference or event

Tags: reactjs, password-protection

As the title suggests, how do you create a password protected React website? Nothing fancy beyond that. Everyone would have access to the same password, no need to do anything super secure, just simply to access the content on the React app.

This is new to me, so I'm not sure the proper steps to take. This is just to protect the content in on the frontend, and it doesn't need to be super secure, mostly to make sure we weed out any truly unauthorized access while our event is going on.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the password-checking logic to your login component. Here are some ideas

Opt 1: use a library, see [react-app-protect](https://github.com/bay0/react-app-protect/issues)

- Note: this currently only works with React 17 or lower

Opt 2: using input + DOM element search

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Login = () => {
  const [isVerified, setIsVerified] = useState(false);

  const checkPw = () => {
    // gets the current input value
    const answer = document.getElementById("password").value;
  
    if (answer === "yourSecretPassword") { 
      setIsVerified(true);
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, that's not it");
    }
  };

 return (
  <>
  {isVerified ? <YourApp />
    :
   (
    <form onSubmit={checkPw}>
     <input id="password" name="password" />
     <button>open sesame</button>
    </form>
  )
}
  </>
;
```

^ This is pretty janky, but it sounds like you're not worried about best-practices.

Comment: Someone could just look at the source and find the password. You would need a server for it to be truly safe from the client.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - thank you! Yes, this project doesn't need to adhere to any password best-practices, so this works perfectly.